# Create a multidimensional array following a pattern

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I am making a 3 dimensional array, using matlab, that progresses according to a pattern. Athough I could write out the Array manually I am sure there is a quicker way to do it.

```
multiArray = cat(3,...
               [1+randn(4,3); 1*randn(4,3)],...
               [2+randn(4,3); 2*randn(4,3)],...
               [3+randn(4,3); 3*randn(4,3)]);
```

If I want to make the above array to be 8x3x25 then the last line would be

```
[25+randn(4,3); 25*randn(4,3)]
```

But how can I make such an array without going through all the tedious intervening steps?

Comment: Factors should probably be 1 2 3 and not 1 3 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [mikkola basically got the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33735222/2732801), there is no need to shift dimensions at the end.

```
s=[4,3,25];
it=reshape(1:s(3),1,1,[]);
out = [bsxfun(@plus , it, randn(s));...
       bsxfun(@times, it, randn(s))];
```

Comment: A nice solution. Especially like parametrising the dimensionality compared to my version.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible way using [`bsxfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html).

```
%// 25 x 4 x 3 with elements for i + randn(4,3)
P = bsxfun(@plus, (1:25)', randn(25,4,3));
%// 25 x 4 x 3 with elements for i * randn(4,3)
T = bsxfun(@times, (1:25)', randn(25,4,3));
%// Concatenate and shift dimensions to get desired size output
multiArray = shiftdim([P T], 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind taking things to `4D` for efficiency purposes -

```
N = 25; %// Number of 3D slices
out = randn(4,2,3,N);
out(:,1,:,:) = bsxfun(@plus,permute(1:N,[1 4 3 2]),out(:,1,:,:));
out(:,2,:,:) = bsxfun(@times,permute(1:N,[1 4 3 2]),out(:,2,:,:));
out = reshape(out,8,3,N);
```

---

To *legitimize* the solution, let's start off with an input of `A = randn(8,3,N)` and initialize the output `out` with it. Also, let's take number of 3D slices as a small number, so say `N = 3`.

Thus,

```
>> N = 3;
A = randn(8,3,N);
out = reshape(A,[4 2 3 N]); %// This replaces "out = randn(4,2,3,N)"
```

Next up, we run the code that will change `out` -

```
>> out(:,1,:,:) = bsxfun(@plus,permute(1:N,[1 4 3 2]),out(:,1,:,:));
out(:,2,:,:) = bsxfun(@times,permute(1:N,[1 4 3 2]),out(:,2,:,:));
out = reshape(out,8,3,N);
```

Now, start validating per `3D` slice -

```
>> out(1:4,:,1) - A(1:4,:,1)
ans =
            1            1            1
            1            1            1
            1            1            1
            1            1            1
>> out(1:4,:,2) - A(1:4,:,2)
ans =
     2     2     2
     2     2     2
     2     2     2
     2     2     2
>> out(1:4,:,3) - A(1:4,:,3)
ans =
     3     3     3
     3     3     3
     3     3     3
     3     3     3
>> out(5:end,:,1)./A(5:end,:,1)
ans =
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
>> out(5:end,:,2)./A(5:end,:,2)
ans =
     2     2     2
     2     2     2
     2     2     2
     2     2     2
>> out(5:end,:,3)./A(5:end,:,3)
ans =
            3            3            3
            3            3            3
            3            3            3
            3            3            3
```